# Hibernate "hbm2ddl - create" does not work in spring

Tags: spring, hibernate

I'm trying to create the table structures automatically with the Hibernate hbm2ddl property, but it only worked when I was using the hibernate.cfg.xml. Now that I've moved to Spring, it does not create the tables automatically when I run my program.

applicationContext.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">

<beans>
    <!-- Data Source Config -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/JEETest" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="123" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate Properties -->
    <bean id="hibernateProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="properties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_transaction</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Session Factory Config -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties" ref="hibernateProperties"></property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.praveen.domain.User</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Layer Mapping -->
    <!-- Login -->
    <bean name="/login" class="com.praveen.action.LoginAction">
        <property name="loginBD" ref="loginBD"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean name="loginBD" class="com.praveen.bd.impl.LoginBDImpl">
        <property name="loginDAO" ref="loginDAO"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean name="loginDAO" class="com.praveen.dao.impl.LoginDAOImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

LoginDAO class -

```
public class LoginDAOImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements LoginDAO {

    public boolean authenticateLogin(String username, String password) throws Exception {
        Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(User.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("username", username));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("password", password));
        User user = (User) criteria.uniqueResult();
        if(user == null){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Domain Class - User.java

```
package com.praveen.domain;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
public class User {
    private int userId;
    private String fName;
    private String lName;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    @Column(nullable=false)
    public String getfName() {
        return fName;
    }
    public void setfName(String fName) {
        this.fName = fName;
    }
    @Column(nullable=false)
    public String getlName() {
        return lName;
    }
    public void setlName(String lName) {
        this.lName = lName;
    }
    @Column(nullable=false, unique=true)
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    @Column(nullable=false)
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

When I run this program I get this error on JSON to the browser :-
{"error":"could not execute query"}

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you get any error? If yes post the same.

Comment: I did just now - at the end of the post

Comment: Can you check the server log?

Comment: I assume this is what you meant. - Located in the logs folder on Tomcat Installation Path.

127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jul/2016:16:42:36 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11418
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [18/Jul/2016:16:42:37 +0530] "GET /JEETest/ HTTP/1.1" 200 526
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [18/Jul/2016:16:42:47 +0530] "POST /JEETest/login.do HTTP/1.1" 200 35
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jul/2016:16:53:10 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11418
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [18/Jul/2016:16:53:10 +0530] "GET /JEETest/ HTTP/1.1" 200 526
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [18/Jul/2016:16:53:16 +0530] "POST /JEETest/login.do HTTP/1.1" 200 35

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the @Table annotation

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "User")
public class User{ .....
```

Comment: Thanks @Niku Hysa... It Works!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to change this from

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
```

to

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
```

Comment: Yes. But it didn't make any difference. The error I get is - could not execute query... By the way making it update cannot help, because I want to create the tables automatically

Comment: Have you tested the configuration if they are correct?

Comment: The config seems right because it already worked on another project. (with hbm2ddl - update) I only changed the params dbname, domain class list & the layer mapping part.

Comment: Does your server prints any error? Can you provide them? 

Your Server error ouput, like Glassfish output!

Comment: It doesn't print an error. It only prints the hibernate select query and then the browser displays the above mentioned error - Could not execute query. I added the e.printStackTrace(); also but no difference

Comment: What browser are you using, there should be a tab called output, where it displays all the log of the server!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117602/discussion-between-niku-hysa-and-praveen-fernando).

Answer (score 0):

I found something interesting.

**The @Table annotation is not mandatory, the problem was that in PostgreSQL, there's a system table named user. Since my domain class also contained the same name, it doesn't let me override that table.**

Now I created another domain class named TestMe without the @Table annotation, only with the @Entity, and it worked!